# Check Validity of JWT on identity server

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, wso2-identity-server

My WSO2 Identity Server issues a JWT, and on my .net core backend, i would like to reach out to Identity Server check the token (perhaps it was revoked for example)...

How do I do that?

Comment: You can do it by enabling introspection. But the access tokens cannot be revoked normally. The only things that ID server persists in database are the reference tokens and user grants.

Comment: what is the endpoint to do that? i've read that around... does the API Manager 1.9.1 has this feature?

Comment: Which identity server are you using? For IdentityServer4 - it's `https://demo.identityserver.io/.well-known/openid-configuration` `"introspection_endpoint":"https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/introspect"`

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see you are using WSO2 ID Server. Here are the links for introspection and discovery endpoint docs: `https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/OAuth2+Token+Validation+and+Introspection` `https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/OpenID+Connect+Discovery`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius tks for the answer, but thats weird... my oauth2 wsdl only lists /authorize, /token, /revoke and /userinfo...

Comment: I’ve not worked with wso2 so not sure if it needs some explicit enabling perhaps. Nethertheless, it is not a recommended approach to use introspection due to extra overhead. That’s why the access tokens are by default very short lifetime usually.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking why you would do that. ANY sensible scenario for this WILL HAVE to involve caching. Which is what a token is.

What we do is this:
* You get 2 tokens, an accesToken and a refresh token.
* The access token is accepted on the backend without questions. It is valid 5 minutes.
* The refresh token is doing a full account check. Revoked? no new access token for you.

Doing exactly the same thing without checking ;)

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't follow... pls guide me though here: my mobile app will issue a request to my api informing a token. if i'm not supposed to reach out to Identity Server, how am i even supposed to check if the token is valid?

Comment: the token should be checked at every request shouldn't it? what if the token was revoked in between? the app will authorize critical operations, wouldn't it? and the basic assumption is that the token is not valid! the whole idea is to know if it is a valid authentication

Comment: ok, but how do i check if the token is not a bunch of random letters and is actually valid?!? how to i know if `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDU0MTcyMTcsImV4cCI6MTU3Njk1MzIxNywiYXVkIjoiYmxhLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6ImpAYmxhLmNvbSIsIkdpdmVuTmFtZSI6IkpvaG5ueSJ9.IpsSmKmglqq1ELRDe9r_HsSjE3MJ6gg5V01x3HR48QI` was actually emitted by my identity Server?!?

Comment: @Leonardo this is done automatically usually because the token signed by identity server and the middlewares that are normally used hit the identity server discovery endpoint to verify the issuer. Anyhow, you can enable introspection at the cost of extra http request overhead to achieve extra verification.